# Alternative to TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection taking ICredentialsProvider

Tags: .net, tfs, sdk, tfs-sdk

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff737874.aspx) the method `GetTeamProjectCollection(RegisteredProjectCollection projectCollection, ICredentialsProvider fallbackCredentialsProvider` of the `TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory` class is now deprecated:

- "Note: This API is now obsolete."
- `[ObsoleteAttribute("This method has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release. See GetTeamProjectCollection(RegisteredProjectCollection) instead.", false)]`

The advice is to use the overload that only takes the `RegisteredProjectCollection`, but what should we use from now on if we want a fallback mechanism for credentials?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the new [TfsTeamProjectCollection constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh723864.aspx) along with this [TfsClientCredentials constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh763965.aspx) which allows interactive prompts for authentication.

```
// Use default windows credentials, and if they fail, AllowInteractive=true
var tfsCreds = new TfsClientCredentials(new WindowsCredential(), true);

TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
    new Uri("http://yourserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"),
    tfsCreds);
```

Comment: It works just fine with VS2010, you need to reference the right assemblies.

Comment: I think the needed assembly is "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll".  I used "11.0.0.0", but the others might work as well.